# Hosting Plans Search?

Tags: web-hosting, search

I'm searching for hosting plans with certain attributes such as memory, drive space and bandwidth limits. The information appears to be scattered around the Internet. A while ago I did find a hosting search engine that allowed you to put in different attributes you require, but I can't seem to find it now. Does anyone know sites that do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SquareCompare](http://www.squarecompare.com/) comes to mind.

Comment: Nice list of web hosts and overview of plans, but it's missing some pretty major players (e.g. DreamHost for shared and Rackspace and Media Temple for VPS). I also wouldn't pick webhosts solely by figures like storage/transfer quotas and price. The real differentiators between good and bad web hosts aren't so easily quantifiable. Always be sure to look for user reviews. You don't want to sign up for a hosting plan with a low monthly rate but terrible service. Also, don't put stock in any hosting _"rating"_ sites that aren't user-review-based.

Comment: @Lèse majesté - They managed to keep things fairly up-to-date when I last used them for advertising (about a year and a half ago), however, I've always recommended asking around forums like webhostingtalk.com for recent reviews of hosts over review sites - web hosts' uptime and support responsiveness change (sometimes dramatically) over time and the trending quality factor is hardest of all to quantify.